# I have tried every solution from stack overflow then too I'm receiving syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE)

Tags: php, syntax-error

```
 <?php

    if ( have_posts() ) 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

?>
```

```
<?php
            endwhile;
                    the_posts_pagination( array(
                        'prev_text'          => "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>".esc_html__(' Prev'),
                        'next_text'          => esc_html__('Next ' )."<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>",
                        'before_page_number' => '',
                    ) ):
            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
            else ;
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
            endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you would need to look before the `endwhile;` for the issue

Comment: How did this code materialize? Why did all the other questions make you think endwhile pairs with else and endif?

Comment: The `if` line has no `{` or `:` to start a block, so the `while` is "inside" the `if` block but your `endwhile` is outside of it.

Answer (score 3):

where are "while():" in your code ?
you need to check your code is structured correctly like this:

```
<?php
while():
// something here
endwhile;
```

Comment: <?php
   if ( have_posts() ) { 
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); {
        ?>
              <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="post">
                  <?php get_template_part('templates/content'); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
       
       }
       }